# How can I import KML from ArcGIS MapServer into QGIS 2.8.3?

Tags: qgis, kml

[image]Can I import KML from http://gis.nature.cz/arcgis/rest/services/PrirodniPomery/Geomorfologie/MapServer into QGIS 2.8.3?

I´m not sure with the duplication. I extracted KML file from KMZ and then I tried load into QGIS. Error message is in czech and it means data source is not in valid or is in unrecognized format, I added structure of kml file.

Answer (score 1):

I'd have to check older versions, but in QGIS 2.14.0 KML docs are added as a *vector* layer via Layer->Add Layer->Add Vector Layer... Specify the source type as "File" and the Source Dataset as the KML file you want to add.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work for this KML file.

Comment: I looked for a more detailed error message (View->Panels->Log Messages Panel) and found "Data source is invalid (ERROR Parseing kml C:\Users\trimble\Documents\example.kml :This file does not fit the OGR model, there is no container element at the root.)" I'm more familiar with <Folder> elements than <NetworkLink> elements in this context. So, I'm still poking around.
I see a couple of references online to this message and the idea that QGIS might not support the full KML standard. I'll have to dig a little more and see what I can find for details.